# $|G|=p^2q$. If $p^2=1\bmod q$ or $q=1\bmod p$, then $G$ is nonabelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The original theorem says:

> $|G|=p^2q$. If $p^2\ne1\bmod q$ and $q\ne1\bmod p$, then $G$ is abelian.

I have proved the above, and now I want to reverse this argument but it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I have so far:

Suppose for a contradiction, $G$ is abelian and ($p^2$=$1$ mod $q$ or $q$ = $1$ $mod$ $p$). Let P and Q be Sylow $p$ and $q$ subgroups, respectively. Since $G$ is abelian, P and Q are both normal in $G$. Hence $n_p=n_q=1$.

Which means $n_p \ne q$ and $n_q \ne p^2$.

On the other hand we have $1+kq=p^2$ for some $k \geq 1$ and $1+kp=q$ for some $k \geq 1$.

But then I'm stuck. Am I going in the wrong direction?

Comment: There is always an abelian group of this size. I think what you want is that there exists a group $G$ of this size which is not abelian, not that all groups of this size are not abelian.

Comment: Hold on, for any finite order, there is a cyclic group of that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original theorem can be written as:

> If $p^2\not\equiv 1\pmod q$ and $q\not\equiv 1\pmod p$ then **for all $G$** with $|G|=p^2q$, $G$ is abelian.

So the converse is:

> If all $G$ with $|G|=p^2q$ are abelian, then $p^2\not\equiv 1\pmod q$ and $q\not\equiv 1\pmod p$.

In turn, the contrapositive of the converse, which you are calling the converse, should be:

> If it is not true that [$p^2\not\equiv 1\pmod q$ and $q\not\equiv 1\pmod p$] then it is not true that every group $G$ with $|G|=p^2q$ is abelian.

This again gets simplified to:

> If $p^2\equiv 1\pmod q$ or $q\equiv 1\pmod p$ then there exists a non-abelian $G$ with $|G|=p^2q$.

The trick is the hidden quantifier, "**for all**" in the original sentence.

If you instead wrote your sentence as:

> **For all** $G$, if $|G|=p^2q$ with $p^2\not\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ and $q\not\equiv 1\pmod p$ then $G$ is abelian.

The the converse is not true.

Comment: The original theorem says: $|G|=p^2q$. If $p^2 ≠ 1$ $mod$ $q$ AND $q ≠ 1$ $mod$ $p$, then $G$ is abelian, but now I want to show that this condition is necessary,

Comment: It's not necessary.

Comment: The theorem you wrote is sort of the contrapositive of what I wrote, but with lazier language. Converse of $A\implies B$ is $B\implies A$. So whour qat you've stated in your question is the contrapositive of the converse. @W.Scott

Comment: But the original theorem is true, I have my own version of the proof, and it's also an established fact.

Comment: Yes, but a theorem being true does not mean its converse is true. @W.Scott

Comment: In any event, the converse here is true (as is the contrapositive of the converse) you are just constructing them wrong because the original theorem's phrasing is vague. The original theorem can be written has: "If $p^2\neq 1\mod q$ and $q\neq 1\mod p$ then **for all** $G$ with $|G|=p^2q$, $G$ is abelian." The key is the hidden quantifier, "for all."

Comment: Is what I'm trying to prove a falsehood?

Comment: We've already shown that what you are trying to prove is a falsehood. Given any $n$, there is always an abelian group of size $n$. I've re-edited my answer from your starting point.

Comment: Thanks! I think I know what I need to prove. Basically show there exists a non abelian group such that p^2=1 mod q or q = 1 mod p.

Comment: For any pair, $p,q$ satisfying $p^2\equiv 1\mod q$ or $q\equiv 1\mod p$, you need to show a non-abelian group $G$ exists. @W.Scott

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56806/discussion-between-w-scott-and-thomas-andrews).